# imgur profile pictures loading over http on https pages

Tags: bug, profile-picture, ssl, imgur

I noticed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array) page all of the gravatars are loaded from imgur using http instead of https, is there a reason for this or is it a bug?

[image: loading Gravatars over http]

Comment: also related: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/  basically https is still in the making